# Misalignment in next privilege tooltip?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

I think there's currently a misalignment in the next privilege tooltip in the user profile.

[image]

Comment: Cross-site dupe of [Improve alignment of “Learn more” button in “Newest badge” popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349013/289905) if the different buttons for _badges_ and _privileges_ are tracked in the same issue.

Comment: @user4642212 ohhh hadn't noticed. But indeed, the other post doesn't mention the occurrence in "Next privilege". Mods feel free to migrate and convert to answer if you prefer. Or leave it on MSO as a signpost to prevent duplicates.