# Small UI bug: The "Learn More" button on pop-up window is off

Tags: bug

The "Learn More" button is a bit off, as shown in the screenshot below (I'm using the dark SO theme). Same issue for light theme. Don't know much about UI, but pretty sure that this should be flushed to the right of the box.

Some system info:

- Browser: Google Chrome 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: Windows 10

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Duplicate of [Misalignment in next privilege tooltip?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398041/misalignment-in-next-privilege-tooltip).

Comment: Yes, it is the same issue.